# How to create some random or unique value in a CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to create some kind of random or unique value in a CloudFormation template?

Why I need this. In our templates we have a number of custom-named resources, for instance `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` with specified `LaunchConfigurationName` or `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` with specified `AutoScalingGroupName`.
When updating stacks, we often get the following error:

> CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename some-stack-launch-configuration and update the stack again.

We don't want to rename resources just because we need to update them.
We also don't want to drop custom names in our resources. We won't mind however having some random suffix in our custom names.

With a "random generator" the solution might look something like:

```
  MyAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: !Sub 'my-auto-scaling-group-${AWS::Random}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to create a `Lambda` function to do this.

Here's a GitHub project [cloudformation-random-string](https://github.com/sophos/cloudformation-random-string), which has a Lambda function and a simple tutorial.

Here's another tutorial [Generate Passwords in AWS CloudFormation Template](https://www.itonaut.com/2018/01/03/generate-passwords-in-aws-cloudformation-template/).

You can refer to the Lambda function above and make it work for you.

Answer (score 24):

If you just need a random ID (no passwords, no fancy requirements), the way I'd recommend is using a portion of [AWS::StackId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-stackid), which is in the following format:

```
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/teststack/51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123
```

So in order to get the last portion, you would need two splits, e.g.:

```
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
          - '-'
          - - my-auto-scaling-group
            - Fn::Select:
                - 4
                - Fn::Split:
                    - '-'
                    - Fn::Select:
                        - 2
                        - Fn::Split:
                            - /
                            - Ref: AWS::StackId
```

Equivalent shorter syntax:

```
AutoScalingGroupName: !Join ['-', ['my-auto-scaling-group', !Select [4, !Split ['-', !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]]]]]
```

Meaning:

1. Start with `AWS::StackId`, e.g.: `arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/teststack/51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123`
2. Split on `/` and select 2th portion (0-indexed): `51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123`
3. Split on `-` and select 4th portion (0-indexed): `1234567db123`
4. Join with your fixed portion name: `my-auto-scaling-group-1234567db123`.

Advantages: I prefer this way than creating a CustomResource, because for large AWS environments and many stacks, you might end up with several lambdas, making governance a bit harder.

Disadvantages: It's more verbose (`Fn::Join`, `Fn::Select`, and `Fn::Split`).

**EDIT 2022-02-17:**

As observed by @teuber789's comment, if you need multiple resources of the same type, e.g.: `my-auto-scaling-group-<random_1>` and `my-auto-scaling-group-<random_2>`, this approach won't work as `AWS::StackId` is the same for whole stack.

Comment: I was unable to get that working, but the following works:
**AutoScalingGroupName: !Join [ "-", ["my-auto-scaling-group", !Select [2, !Split [ "/", !Ref 'AWS::StackId']]]]**

Comment: That's a great option too, @Nipazz! Just keep in mind that splitting only on "/" might break the name length limit for some AWS resources.

Comment: This solution will fail for the OP's question. Stack ID will not change during cloudformation update. So any resource which is named using full/partial stack Id cannot be updated due to AWS restriction on custom named resources.

Comment: Hey @satya, that only stands true if the property undergoing an update requires **replacement**. For example `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` has the majority of its properties under the *requires replacement* regime, and therefore it's indeed not recommended to have it with a custom name. The cfn doc usually have these things well-document. For `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`, only `InstanceId` currently requires replacement, thus this approach seems OK.

Comment: This only works if you only have one resource in a stack that needs a string of random characters. If you have multiple resources of the same type defined in the same stack that each need a random identifier string, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: That's true, @teuber789. The stack ID is the same for the whole stack. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 11):

this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67162053/2660313 but shorter:

```
Value: !Select [2, !Split ['/', !Ref AWS::StackId]]
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the most elegant way to implement such logic (if you don't want to rename resources) is to use Cloudformation [Macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html). They're like a custom resource, but you call them implicitly during template transformation.
So, I will try to provide some example, but you can investigate more in [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

First of all, you create the function (with all required permissions and so on) that will do the magic (something like **LiuChang** mentioned).

Then, you should create a macro from this Function:

```
Resources:
    Macro:
      Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Macro
      Properties:
        Name: <MacroName>
        Description: <Your description>
        FunctionName: <Function ARN>
```

And then use this Macro in your resources definition:

```
MyAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: 
        'Fn::Transform':
         - Name: <MacroName>
           Parameters:
             InputString: <Input String>
             ...<Some other parameters like operation type or you can skip this>
```

Also, to use macros, you should specify the **CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND** capability during stack creation/updation.

And that's it. It should just work, but of course one of the drawbacks of this approach - you should maintain additional lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the AWS Java SDK to run some Stack Update command.

I generate random value using Java, then I pass it as parameter.