# How to add random suffix values to resource custom name in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating cloudformation resource with custom name with random suffix

CF stack template Attach template:

```
MyMacro:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Macro
    Properties:
      Name: 'random-string'
      Description: 'random string generator'
      FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxx:function:random-string'
  CreateSGLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DependsOn: MyMacro
    Properties:
      RoleName: 
        *Fn::Transform:
          - Name: MyMacro
            Parameters:
              InputString: ud-sg-MyMacro*
```

I need a role name like 'ud-sg-ABCD123'.

I am getting the following error for creating this CF stack:

> No transform named ::MyMacro found.. Rollback requested by user.

Comment: See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660653/how-to-create-some-random-or-unique-value-in-a-cloudformation-template

Comment: @john, i am trying the same way, but not successfull
AutoScalingGroupName: 
        `'Fn::Transform':
         - Name: <MacroName>
           Parameters:
             InputString: <Input String>
             ...<Some other parameters like operation type or you can skip this>`